# Embedding live feed from IP cam into website with https and authentication

Tags: javascript, html, networking, webcam

So I know your first thought: "Great. Another guy who doesn't know how to use the search button." However, My situation is a little unique. Add the fact that I have been trying to accomplish a simple feat for over 10 hours now implies that I hope you understand where I am coming from.

First off, I am a novice programmer with some knowledge of html and CSS. However, my depth of knowledge of JS is lacking.

**Goal:** to integrate an IP cam feed into a website I am currently developing

**What I have tried thus far:**

Using the following code to first login to the UI of the webcam (using the external IP address and port number)and grabbing the stream off of the UI and displaying it onto my webpage:

```
<img src="https://[IP ADDRESS OF IP CAM:PORT NUMER]/snapshot.cgi?username=[username]&password=[password]&t=" onload='setTimeout(function() {src = src.substring(0, (src.lastIndexOf("t=")+2))+(new Date()).getTime()}, 1000)' onerror='setTimeout(function() {src = src.substring(0, (src.lastIndexOf("t=")+2))+(new Date()).getTime()}, 5000)' alt='please wait 2' />
```

Additionally, I have tried using the following code to open a new window and login to the UI separately so that it would bypass the authentication requirements:

```
<script>
function login() {
document.form.action="https://[IP ADDRESS OF IP CAM: PORT NUMBER]/login.cgi?uri=/";
document.form.submit();
}

</script>
</HEAD>
<BODY onLoad="login()">
<FORM NAME="form" METHOD="post">
<input type="hidden" id="uri"  name="uri" value=" /" />
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" id="username" NAME="username" VALUE="[username]">
<INPUT TYPE="hidden" id="password" NAME="password" VALUE="[password]">
<input type="hidden" value=" Login" />

</FORM>
```

So why try option number 2? The reason is that if I am running the website AND am logged into the camera via the external IP address, the camera feed shows perfectly (using the first block of code). However, the moment I log out of the camera, the feed seizes and quits working.

I have done endless google searches and I am at my last hope. Any advice that anyone could offer me would be greatly appreciated. Since I can view the feed perfectly on the webpage if I am logged on (same computer) to the camera using the external IP address, I know I can't be too far away from achieving victory.

Also, the second code block fails to bring log in. It will take me to the UI login page of the camera but say: "invalid credentials"

Thank you all

Comment: The HTML form is completely ignored, and there is a "198" before the URL. side note: use lowercase HTML tags please.

Comment: @Raptor also, what do you mean by the html form is completely ignored?

Comment: when the HTML is loaded, the `onload` event already triggered the `login()` and submit the form without letting the user to enter user name & password. Is it the desired behavior?

Comment: No I'm sorry. The first thing that should happen is the webpage to load, then the username and password should be entered and then the submit button should be clicked

Comment: then you should remove the `onload` event, and make a submit button instead. Also, make sure the CGI reads POST request, as it's a GET request in your first example.

Comment: @Raptor could you give me an example of that? I'm sorry as my JS knowledge isn't the best